# Can match specifications be used only for tracing and selecting from ets tables? Can they be used in a case expression?

Tags: erlang

Is there a way to use a match specification to select between different clauses of a function? I've seen match specifications used only for either tracing or matching entries in ets tables.

Example of what I want to do:

In user supplied file:

```
Module(m1),  
Function(f1),  
Guard([ %% list of match specifications follows:  
  %% First (and only in this case) match spec:  
   { [{score, '$1', '$2', '$3'}, '$4'], 
       [{is_atom, '$1'}, {is_pid, '$2'}, {is_atom, '$3'}], 
     [true] }  
  ]).
```

From this file I want to generate code. What's important for me is to be able to use the match specifications in the Guard to be able to filter out the clauses of f1 such that I can know when the first argument of f1 was a tuple of the form {score, First, Second, Third} and is_atom(First), is_pid(Second), is_atom(Third).

Is there a way for me to generate code like this:

```
case some_unknown_function(MatchSpec, F1Args) of
  true ->
    %% f1's clause matches the MatchSpec
    ;
  false ->
    %% f1's clause does not match the MatchSpec
end.
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [`ets:match_spec_compile/1`](http://erldocs.com/R15B/stdlib/ets.html?i=14&search=ets:match#match_spec_compile/1) and [`ets:match_spec_run/2`](http://erldocs.com/R15B/stdlib/ets.html?i=15&search=ets:match#match_spec_run/2), they do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you Adam. I ended opting out of match specs for now and have taken a different approach. But I didn't know about these functions, so thanks again!